# GMap.NET winforms. Ground Overlays functionality(upload external piece of map)

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, gmap.net

I want do something like this in gmap view:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays

I can put polygon and fill with texture, its work but I have problem with behalf of this texture and mapping this texture to map view. For example when I press zoom texture will be broke.

```
GMapOverlay polygons = new GMapOverlay("polygons");
List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.863868, 2.321554));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.861017, 2.330030));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(48.863727, 2.331918));
GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "Jardin des Tuileries");

polygon.Fill = new TextureBrush();//here i can put texture
polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);

polygons.Polygons.Add(polygon);
gmap.Overlays.Add(polygons);
```

Answer (score 1):

GMapControl.Overlays are limited to Markers, Polygons and Routes

You could use

https://github.com/SharpMap

for such overlays